# External Monitor Ubunut

Tags: 22.04, monitor, syslinux

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my MSI GF65 Thin laptop. I am trying to connect it to a monitor using hdmi cable; the cable works when I use it on windows OS or my ps4 but I am failing to connect to my monitor when using ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

MSI GF65 Thin laptop has its HDMI port directly connected to the nvidia GPU. So unless you have the nvidia GPU running using the latest drivers, the HDMI output will not work.

To solve this problem, go into the "Additional Drivers" tab in your ubuntu software & updates app, select the latest Nvidia driver and apply it. You may have to restart the laptop once.

When your laptop starts up again, ensure that you have a new app installed - "Nvidia X server settings", go into "PRIME profiles" and select "Nvidia (performance mode)" if not already selected. This selection requires another reboot (if you had to switch any selection here).

Once you are back on with Nvidia GPU set to performance mode, you will be able to use an external display using HDMI cable.

Please note: This works only with X11 windowing system, it does not work yet with Wayland. This may change in an upcoming LTS release (24.04)